# Passing variable from Magento

Tags: magento

I created a custom module in Magento that creates a variable with an array of order information anytime an order is placed. I now need to create some sort of mechanism or procedure that sends these variables to an external database. However, I'm not sure which route to take. Can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Here's what I have so far for the Observer.php file:

```
<?php
class Companyname_Dataport_Model_Observer
{
    public function orderPaid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $orderId = $observer->getPayment()->getOrder()->getId();

        $orderdata = array();
        $orderdata['id'] = $order->getIncrementId();
        $orderdata['customername'] = $order->getCustomerFirstname() . " " . $order->getCustomerLastname();
        $orderdata['price'] = $order->getPrice();
        $orderdata['items'] = array();
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
            $item = array();

            $item['productid'] = $orderItem->getProductId();
            $item['qty'] = $orderItem->getQtyOrdered();

            $orderdata['items'][] = $item;
        }

        // Writing to the DOM

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recomend you to use an observer, listening to an event related to order creation.
For example, you could listen to `sales_order_save_after` and in the observer your method will take as parameter `$observer`. You can then access the order data with `$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();`.
Here is some code:

1. **config.xml**:

   ```
   <config>
       ...
       <global>
           ...
           <events>
               <sales_order_save_after>
                   <observers>
                       <some_descriptive_string>
                           <type>singleton</type>
                           <class>themodelalias/observer</class>
                           <method>theMethodToUse</method>
                       </some_descriptive_string>
                   </observers>
               </sales_order_save_after>
           </events>
           ...
       </global>
       ...
   </config>
   ```
2. **Observer.php**:

   ```
   class Yournamespace_Yourmodule_Model_Observer
   {
       public function theMethodToUse($observer)
       {
           $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
           //here goes your code to send the information to your external db
       {
   }
   ```

Comment: This is very close to the approach I've taken, but I'm stuck on how to code the part that sends the information to the external db. Any chance you could help with that? I've edited the original post to include what I have so far for the Observer.php file.

Comment: is it on the same host? do you want to insert directly onto db or send to a script to another domain?

Comment: We need to send it to database on another domain. I'm inexperienced in this area and am trying to learn, but I've had a tough time finding something comparable. Any help with coding out the syntax would be great. My thoughts now are to somehow create an XML file, then pass it along to the remote server.

Comment: there's an extension for conecting to external db: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/the3tree/extension/6428/ttt_edb : try it out

Answer (score 1):

You can go around this several ways, here are two of them that I would go for:

**1)** Easiest: at the moment where the order is placed and you have the information, you can use PHP exec() function to call a standalone PHP file. (Where the variables are passed ofcourse)

Example:

```
exec("php /path/to/standalone/script.php ". $variable);
```

(You might need to json_encode $variable if it's an array)

This script just used the variables and connects to a local/remote database to run a query and update the information.

**2)** You could create a web service on the external server that can be called whenever you want from Magento

There are still other ways to do this but I hope my answer contains useful information already that can get you started.

Comment: Kenny - What do you think about placing the script, instead of in a standalone PHP file, in the Observer.php file? Also, where could I find help in how to code out the script?

Comment: Hi, I was talking about putting the line that I provided in an Observer.php or any other file that you use within your magento module. I simply pointed out how you could contact the other database, that is through an exec() or a webservice as I pointed out in my reply. In the reply above where the "//here goes your code to send the information to your external db" is written you can simply copy paste my exec() line I provided. As for coding the standalone php script that handles the insertion on the remote database I would go for basic mysql_query functions.

Comment: Thanks for the post. So, to clarify your suggestion, you would include the "exec" line in your Observer.php file, and that would complete the entire Observer.php file? Then you'd recommend creating a separate file that would include the basic mysql_query functions? Sorry to be so thickheaded.

Comment: I would only place a standalone file somewhere to reduce the overhead of inserting the data into the other remote database. This would keep all logic for inserting data in the other database inside 1 file, separated from magento's logic. All magento needs to do is grab all the info that is needed and pass it to the standalone script which then handles all the remote inserting ;) Feel free to accept/vote up if this has helped you :D

Answer (score 1):

you can use cURL.... directly write the code in your observer.php. you will need the followung things while writing the curl....

1. url: the url where you would like to send the data
2. A user key and Secret
3. A script to receive your data at the remote site.

Your data would be sent in json format.... Here is a sample sender example:

```
$xurl='http://domain/Observer_test/';//open bravo or any other application's endpoint here
                        $curl = curl_init();
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $xurl);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "111:abc");
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("data" => json_encode($data)));
                        $resp = curl_exec($curl);

                        curl_close($curl);
                        $resp = json_decode($resp);
```

And the sample receiver code in php(can be in any language):

```
$userkey=$_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"];
$usersecret=$_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"];
$key = '111';//16 character
        $secret = 'abc';//32 character
        if(!($userkey==$key  && $usersecret==$secret))  {
        http_response_code(403);

}else{
    $data = $_POST["data"];

    $dir='/path/to/save/file';
    $file = new SplFileObject($dir."fread.txt", "w");

    $written = $file->fwrite($data);
    if($written){
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        http_response_code(200);
        echo json_encode(array("stat"=>"SUCCESS"));
    }
}
```

So basically it is a web service following REST architecture